# How to save a bookmark in multiple folders in an internet browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet, browser

I have a bookmark in Chrome browser and I'd like to put the same bookmark in multiple folders. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can copy a bookmark from a folder into another.

For chrome, menu -> bookmarks -> bookmark manager, find the bookmark right click, copy, go to another folder and paste it.

For firefox, click the icon on the right of the star icon and 'show all bookmarks'. The rest is the same.

Comment: This is a little unclear and shouldn't be followed literally, but is correct in principle.  The main thing is that the only way (AFAIK) to create a duplicate is to type/paste the URL into a new bookmark in the second folder, created using the Bookmark Manager.

Comment: @EdStaub I agree with Ed. I did not see a paste option in the second folder even when you right click on the second folder, the menu that appears has no paste option. You need to open the second folder->right click on any empty space there and click `Add new bookmark`->on the little form that appears, in `title` type name of the bookmark and in `url` box paste the url you copied from the first folder.

Comment: Seems to be a hidden feauture (other word for bug)

Comment: No bug. Useful. Issue is rather that Chrome browser does not carry a native tool for managing bookmarks (incl. clean-up of dead links and subjects out of place / multiple entries). And I agree with @nam - this is the way to do it. No right click option is available.

Answer (score 7):

If the page URL in question does not have a question mark '?' in it, you can append some random numbers prepended with '?' like this:

```
http://brightside.me/article/15-unusual-but-seriously-effective-tips-to-help-you-communicate-better-34855/?1
```

If the URL contains a '?' you can append '&1' to the end of the URL, like this:

```
http://example.com/post.php?id=123&1
```

Now your browser should think it is a different webpage, so it allows you to put it in a new location, without the other bookmark's folder being changed.

Downsides:

- The bookmark will appear multiple times when searching for it via location field.

Answer (score 3):

In bookmarks manager ...

1. Highlight the website that you want to copy.
2. Right click it, and select "Copy URL."
3. Click the folder that you want to copy the website to.
4. Hit CTRL+V to paste the website in the new folder.